# How do I access a Control type variable's possible properties?

Tags: c#

I have a Control type variable that will be set to either a combo box or a text box.I cannot access the selection start property from the control variable. This must be because that data type is a parent to controls that do not have that property. How can I get around this to access the selection start property?

The code:

```
private void createText(string lowerCaseChar, string upperCaseChar)
        {
            Control FocusedTextComboBox;

            switch (lastTextComboBoxFocused)
            {
                case 54:
                    FocusedTextComboBox = SearchTextBox;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    FocusedTextComboBox = VendorComboBox;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    FocusedTextComboBox = VendorComboBox;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    FocusedTextComboBox = DeptComboBox;
                    break;
            }

            if (SearchTextBox.SelectionStart == 0 && SearchTextBox.Text != "")
            {
                switch (shift)
                {
                    case true:
                        FocusedTextComboBox.Text += upperCaseChar;
                        break;
                    case false:
                        FocusedTextComboBox.Text += lowerCaseChar;
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                int SelectionStartNumber = FocusedTextComboBox.SelectionStart;

                switch (shift)
                {
                    case true:
                        FocusedTextComboBox.Text = FocusedTextComboBox.Text.Insert(FocusedTextComboBox.SelectionStart, upperCaseChar);
                        break;
                    case false:
                        FocusedTextComboBox.Text = FocusedTextComboBox.Text.Insert(FocusedTextComboBox.SelectionStart, lowerCaseChar);
                        break;
                }
                FocusedTextComboBox.SelectionStart = SelectionStartNumber + 1;
            }

            FocusedTextComboBox.Focus();
        }
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve with those magic numbers, but is there any reason why you don't just access `SearchTextBox` directly, skipping the `switch`?

Comment: The numbers are the index of the controls I want to access. And the method needs to be able to effect multiple controls

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that it is a data type issue.  You need to cast the `object` type to `textbox` to be able to access the selection start property.

```
if(FocusedTextComboBox is TextBox)
   SelectionStartNumber = (FocusedTextComboBox as TextBox).SelectionStart
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending user3529814's answer, declare a local variable as a TextBox and cast your control so you can use it throughout the block:

```
        if (FocusedTextComboBox is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)FocusedTextComboBox;

            if (SearchTextBox.SelectionStart == 0 && SearchTextBox.Text != "")
            {
                switch (shift)
                {
                    case true:
                        tb.Text += upperCaseChar;
                        break;
                    case false:
                        tb.Text += lowerCaseChar;
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                int SelectionStartNumber = tb.SelectionStart;

                switch (shift)
                {
                    case true:
                        tb.Text = tb.Text.Insert(tb.SelectionStart, upperCaseChar);
                        break;
                    case false:
                        tb.Text = tb.Text.Insert(tb.SelectionStart, lowerCaseChar);
                        break;
                }
                tb.SelectionStart = SelectionStartNumber + 1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks,
Is there a way that I could be more general and assign a variable the type of either textbox or combo box and then use that to cast?

Comment: That's basically what you're doing with the `Control` type...but if you want to use any property that is specific to either the ComboBox or the TextBox then you have to cast it first...